# How to make update function of hashlib md5 work in both Python 2 and Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, md5, hashlib

I want to create a hash of `string_variable`.

In **Python2**:

```
def get_hash_python2(string_variable):
  import hashlib
  m = hashlib.md5()
  m.update(string_variable) # this takes string as argument
  return m.digest()
```

In **Python3**:

```
def get_hash_python3(string_as_bytes)
  import hashlib
  m = hashlib.md5()
  m.update(string_as_bytes) # this takes bytes as argument
  return m.digest()
```

How to write a single `get_hash` function to get hash for the `string_variable` that would be compatible with both **Python2** and **Python3**?

Comment: you have 2 questions, how to use `hashlib.md5.update()` on strings, and how to make one code file that works in v2 and v3.

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.encode` to convert the string variable to the appropriate form acceptable by hashlib

**Both on Python2 and Python3**

```py
import hashlib

def get_hash(string_variable):
    m = hashlib.md5()
    m.update(string_variable.encode())
    return m.digest()
```

Answer (score 0):

In python3 if i am not wrong

```py
m.update(b"string_as_bytes")
```

Comment: Thanks. In my case, I don't have a hardcoded string but it's in a variable `string_variable`.

Comment: try def get-hash(b"string_variable") not sure if will work but im just giving ideas

Answer (score 0):

Back when I wrote code to run in either Python2 or Python3 I would often have both a Python2 version and a different Python3 version, in an `if` that checked which version.  I would usually cheat on the version test like:

```
if bytes == str:
    def my_function():
        ...
        # Python2 version of code goes here.
        ...
else:
    def my_function():
        ...
        # Python3 version of code goes here.
        ...
```

This version test only works in version 2.6 and 2.7 of Python2.

To convert a string that only has values in it that are numerically from 0 to 255, you can do this:

```
bytes_var = bytes(ord(x) for x in str_var)
```

This only works in Python3.  By changing `bytes` to `bytearray` it works in both Python2 and Python3.

Comment: i only code for python3 these days and i am starting to forget some of the differences in python2.